# Javascript create dynamic variables based on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object defined below.

```
var obj = { 'group': ['a', 'b'],
            'value': 10
          }
```

Please note that group array can have n values. This is just an example. 
I want to create dynamic variables with names in array and assign their sum equal to value i.e 10. So for this particular object I want the following result.

```
First create Variables
var a, b
Then assign a + b = 10
```

Similarly for n values in array, I want

```
var a,b, ...n
a+b+....+n = 10
```

Comment: Please add more detail. Is `a=10` and `b=0` what you want? It satisfies `a+b=10`.

Comment: why do you need that? you could use an object, as you already have and use it as a namwspace for the dynamic need.

Comment: What code did you try? Where is your problem? You should check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as this question is not "a valid stackoverflow" question

Comment: *assing a+ b =10* What ? Why ? How ? What is your final goal ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a function in your object, if i understand you right

```
var obj = {
    group: [1, 2, 3],
    value: function(){
        return this.group.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    }
}

obj.value();//6
```

you can edit obj.group array and get new value of this array by calling function obj.value()

but if you mean(again not sure, cause it is hard to understand) to make this value from variables called "a", "b" and etc you can try this code

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;

var obj = {
    group: ["a", "b"],
    value: function(){
        return this.group.reduce((v_prev, v_current) => v_prev + eval(v_current), 0);
    }
}

obj.value();//3
```

Not the best idea to use eval, but it works. This code will find the sum of variables "a" and "b"

Answer (score 0):

look at this code i think this would help you:

```
    var obj = {
    'group': [5, 5],
    'value':function(str){
       return this[str].reduce(add)
    }
};

function add(a,b){
  return a+b
}

console.log(obj.value('group'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object instead:

```js
var obj = {
  'group': ['a', 'b'],
  'value': 10
}

var groupNames = obj.group,
  groupCount = groupNames.length,
  val = obj.value / groupCount, //divide the obj.value to total group count
  resultObj = {};

for (var i in groupNames) {
  resultObj[groupNames[i]] = val; //add properties to resultObj based on group name and assign its value
}

//you can use the object properties to access your "dynamically created variables"
for (var i in resultObj) {
  console.log('Your variable name is "' + i + '" and the value is ' + resultObj[i])
}
```

***NOTE:*** It is not sure the logic on `a + b + ... n = obj.val` so, I have used average.

That is - `obj.val / obj.groups.length`.